# React Native Create Views Issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have two views. ViewA is fixed size (60 * 60), and remaining space is for ViewB. How can I create these Views in React Native ?
The image below is sample view that I want to create.

View code i'd tried:

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', height: 60, backgroundColor: 'green', flexDirection: 'row' }}> 
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', flex: 2 }}/> 
    <View style={{ flex: 1, with: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'purple', }}/>
</View>
```

[image]

Comment: Share the code part that you'd tried.

Comment: @dhilmathy Here it is 
<View style={{
        width: '100%',  
        height: 60, 
        backgroundColor: 'green', 
        flexDirection: 'row' 
      }}>
        <View style={{
          backgroundColor: 'pink', 
          flex: 2 
        }}>
        </View>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,  
          with: 60, 
          height: 60, 
          backgroundColor: 'purple', 
        }}>
        </View>

Answer (score 1):

Okay this should work.
import Dimensions from react-native.

```
<View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width - 60, backgroundColor: "pink" }}></View>
        <View style={{ width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: "purple" }}></View>
    </View>
```

Comment: Thank for responding. but I want purple view's width: 60 and height: 60

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding to the top.

working demo: https://snack.expo.io/Syp9bUrDm

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', height: 60, backgroundColor: 'green', flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 20 }}> 
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', flex: 2 }}/> 
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width: 60, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'purple', }}/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for this concept

```
<View style={{ flex:1, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'green', flexDirection: 'row' }}> 
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'pink', flex: 0.6 }}/> 
    <View style={{ flex: 0.4, backgroundColor: 'purple', }}/>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank for responding. but I want purple view's width: 60 and height: 60

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{ width: '100%', flex:1, height: 60, backgroundColor: 'green', flexDirection: 'row-reverse', paddingTop: 20 }}> 

            <View style={{ height: 60,width:60, backgroundColor: 'purple', }}/>
            <View style={{ height: 60,backgroundColor: 'pink', alignSelf:'stretch', flex:1 }}>

            </View> 
        </View>
      </View>
```

Check for this in https://snack.expo.io/@saravanansivalingam/top-padding